# Are there any tools which can autopopulate multiple features with metadata fields in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml, metadata, esri-geoportal-server

I have an enterprise geodatabase which contains hundreds of feature classes.  I would like to publish the metadata from each feature to geoportal server in FGDC format.  Is there an out of the box tool/script which allows users to pre-populate fields for all data sets in a geodatabase?  Ideally, features such as originator, date, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to create the metadata you want common to all your datasets,  you do this by filling in one dataset then export to xml. Create a model that cycles through your datasets importing the xml. This will overwrite any existing metadata. It is discussed here:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000000z000000